# Understanding ES6 javascript proxies

Tags: javascript, es6-proxy

I'm trying to register function change via proxies with this code:

```
const handler = {
  construct(objTarget, args, oldConstructor) {
     return new objTarget(...args)
  },
  set(target, key, value) {
    console.log(`Setting value ${key} as ${value}`)
    target[key] = value;
  },
  get(target, key) {
    console.log(`Reading value from ${key}`)
    return target[key];
  },
};

function wand (args){console.log(args)}

const Wand = new Proxy(wand, handler);

var w = new Wand(["some","args"]);
```

When I type

```
Wand.a = 10
```

I get output

```
>Setting value a as 10
```

But if i type

```
w.a = 10
```

Handler "get" outputs nothing

How do i get code working for "w.a = 10"? This is part of [codewars.com](https://www.codewars.com/kata/priori-incantatem/train/javascript) challenge, so

```
var w = new Wand(["some","args"]);
```

is predefined and I can't modify it.

PS: Please, don't spoil how to accomplish this challenge, I'd like to know only how to get this part done. Or suggest another way how to get this done.

Thank you!

Comment: Well you've only proxied `Wand`, not `w`. The proxy will not magically extend to any return value or accessed property. You need to create a new proxy when a `new Wand` is made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice the `handler.construct()` is simply

```
return new objTarget(...args)
```

There's nothing special about the returned value, it's just an instance of the proxy's target `wand` so something like

```
return new Proxy(new objTarget(...args), someHandler)
```

would allow you to intercept operations on `w` based on the traps defined in `someHandler`.

Comment: Thank you it works now. I noticed that later but i wasn't sure what to do about that :)

Comment: Hint: you don't need to intercept the construction at all, `Wand` should not be a proxy. You can control directly what the `Wand` function does.

Comment: @Bergi it was stated that this was for a challenge where some of the code could not be modified. I didn't look at the challenge myself, but this suggestion led to the least modification necessary to accomplish what was requested. You're welcome to write an answer for returning the proxy from the constructor itself if you want though.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts is there any way how to make `(new Wand() instanceof Wand) == true` with this code?

Comment: @Chiffre without a `TypeError`? Yes, change ``console.log(`Reading value from ${key}`)`` to ``console.log(`Reading value from ${String(key)}`)``